# How do i pick a specific value on a JSON (Webhook) Data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, webhooks

I need to store a specific value of a JSON data into a variable. I'm trying to store the value of **Name** (John) into a `var name = ""`.

I'm trying to do `var name = data.Name` but is not working (returns undefined).

Can I get some help on how to pick and store that data?

Thanks! this is the parsed JSON data:

````
   console.log(event.data);
    
   var data = {};

   if (event.data) {
     data = JSON.parse(event.data);
   }

   console.log(data)```

   *************CONSOLE LOG JSON PARSED:***************
   ``` { id: '1602163471805-0',
  indexed_at_ms: 1602163471805,
  event:
   { bodyRaw:
      '{"IsEnabled":false,"Id":"684a3a9b-d810-4310-b1f5-037257cea549","Type":"Customer","RoleType":"NaturalPerson","PermissionType":"Group","ParticipantPermission":"None","Name":"Dessa vez vai","Email":"21979478857@octachat.com","ThumbUrl":"https://octadeskstorage.blob.core.windows.net/whatsapp/thumb/inovaimobiliaria/5521979478857_1601418104.jpeg","Groups":[],"Products":[],"CustomField":{"bairro1":"Centro","renda1":"De R$3.000 até R$6.000","chat_profissao":"Oi"},"PhoneContacts":[{"Number":"21900908876"},{"Number":"21979478857"},{"Number":"21997899090"},{"Number":"21945457671"},{"Number":"21989776652"},{"Number":"21934356678"},{"Number":"2189998333"},{"Number":"21988765543"}],"Organizations":[{"Id":"a7bf89b7-9966-4a7e-b11e-51eea80aea51","Name":"Octachat"}]}',
     path: '/',
     method: 'POST',
     query: {},
     body:
      { ParticipantPermission: 'None',
        Organizations: [Array],
        PhoneContacts: [Array],
        Id: '684a3a9b-d810-4310-b1f5-037257cea549',
        CustomField: [Object],
        Email: '21979478857@octachat.com',
        Products: {},
        Groups: {},
        Name: 'John',
        ThumbUrl:
         'https://octadeskstorage.blob.core.windows.net/whatsapp/thumb/inovaimobiliaria/5521979478857_1601418104.jpeg',
        IsEnabled: false,
        Type: 'Customer',
        RoleType: 'NaturalPerson',
        PermissionType: 'Group' },
     headers:
      { host: '35057ec8a10b30b1f3e501cb372ad49e.m.pipedream.net',
        'x-forwarded-for': '35.199.105.184',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        accept: 'application/json',
        'content-length': '760',
        'x-forwarded-proto': 'https',
        'x-amzn-trace-id': 'Root=1-5f7f130f-453544bf4f234e2607a4451e',
        'x-forwarded-port': '443' } },
  metadata:
   { emit_id: '1ib5V6BEw0NiITr1HMtRp8H0Tsr',
     emitter_id: 'dc_AjuaVp',
     name: '',
     summary: 'POST /' } }``
````

Comment: Hi, so just to make sure, this JSON object is what you get when you log data?

Comment: Already tried data.body.Name, still undefined, and yes, this is the log data (after the JSON Parse)

Comment: Try data.event.body.Name?

Comment: my bad... `var name = data.event.body.Name` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go deeper in the object. `Name` is nested inside it.

```js
if (event.data) {
    data = JSON.parse(event.data);
    const name = data.event.body.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

var name = data.event.body.Name

your name is in 4th level of your Json.